# String modified value after calling what() in a extension of std::exception

Tags: c++

I am working on a project for university and I got this error. In a function, if a file doesn't exist, we throw an error. This error is catched and I want to print the message of the error. The problem is that when I print the what() return string, the string prints some "random" ascii.

I replicated this error in this code:

**main.cpp**

```
int main() {
    Prueba a;
    try{
        a.function();
    }catch(file_not_found_exception& fnf){
        std::cout << fnf.what() << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Prueba.h**

```
class Prueba {
public:
    void function() noexcept(false);
};
```

**Prueba.cpp**

```
void Prueba::function(){
    throw file_not_found_exception("file.n");
}
```

**error.h**

```
class file_not_found_exception : public std::exception{
private:
    std::string message = "File not found", file = "";
public:
    file_not_found_exception() = default;
    explicit file_not_found_exception(const std::string& file_t){
        file = file_t;
    }
    const char *what() const noexcept override{
        if(file.empty())
            return message.c_str();
        else{
            std::string error_message = message+": "+file;
            const char* error_message_conversion = error_message.c_str();
            return error_message_conversion;
        }

    }
};
```

When I run the program I get the output:

> └■
>
> Hello, World!

My question is: why does this happend and how could I fix it?. When I debug and check the value in error_message(error.h) and error_message_conversion(error.h) the values are fine, is just when the value is returned that it bugs.

Im using CLion 2019.3 and GCC-8.2.0-5.

Comment: `error_message` is a local variable, you return a dangling pointer.

Comment: @Evg You should post an answer. Also, `message` should be declared `static const` and `file` should be initialized with an initializer, not in the constructor body.

Comment: @Ted Actually I don’t think this is correct anyway. The thrown exception is allocated in such a way that catching it by non-const ref seems to be legal.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I think you are correct.

Comment: Yes, exceptions are stored in a special place, and there is no requirement to catch them by `const` ref (though a ref is ideal because copying them removes the benefit of that special storage, and `const` just makes logical sense). But you don't have to worry about temporaries or lifetime or anything like that.

Comment: @ErikT Suggestion for C++17: `struct file_not_found_exception : std::filesystem::filesystem_error {
    file_not_found_exception(const std::filesystem::path& path) :
        std::filesystem::filesystem_error(
            path,
            std::make_error_code(std::errc::no_such_file_or_directory)
        )
    {}
};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::string error_message = message+": "+file;
const char* error_message_conversion = error_message.c_str();
return error_message_conversion;
```

`error_message` has automatic storage. It will be automatically destroyed at the end of the scope, which is at the end of the function. You return a pointer to the string owned by `error_message`. The pointer immediately becomes invalid as soon as the automatic variable is destroyed.

When you access the destroyed string through the invalid pointer after calling `what()`, the behaviour of the program is undefined.

Returning `message.c_str()` would be fine. You could modify the member variable in the constructor to have the desired value. The interface of `std::exception` simply cannot work with generating the string upon a call to `what()`.

Comment: You have a few typoes.

Comment: @Spencer I found one. Edit: and another. And a missing word.

Comment: This was it! I copied the value to a char*, returned the char* and now it prints it correctly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ErikT. When you say you "copied the value to a char*", what do you mean exactly? A `char*` cannot store a string, it can only point to one. So did you create a new buffer? What are its ownership semantics? Is it leaked?

Comment: It would be better to store the "final" string as a `std::string` member (computed in the constructor) as eerorika suggested, then you can safely return the result of `c_str()`

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings you are right, a std::string is a much better option.